# Rendering a Resource Area Cell after an Event is added to the Resource lane

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When the calendar is loaded and rendered cellDidMount is called and the cell is rendered green or red this works fine. What I want to do is re-render the cell a different colour when an event is added to the recource lane some time later. How can I call this cellDidMount for a partiular resouce or do somethign else after an event function like select or dateClick is called and a new event is added.

```
resourceAreaColumns: [
    {
        headerContent: 'Resource',
        field: 'title'
    },
    {
        headerContent: 'Tasks',
        field: 'tasks',
        width: 50,
        headerDidMount: function(arg) {
            arg.el.style.textAlign = "center";
        },
        cellDidMount: function (arg) {
            var parentId = arg.resource._resource.parentId;
            var tasks = arg.resource._resource.extendedProps.tasks;
            if (parentId != "" && tasks == 0)
                arg.el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            else
                arg.el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            arg.el.style.textAlign = "center";
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Are you referring to fullCalendar 5? Or another version? It would help if we knew

Comment: Either way I would guess if you [refetch the resources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/refetchResources) it will probably cause them to re-render, which in turn will run the rendering hooks

Comment: Sorry yes v5.2 but refetch / re-render does not re-run the hooks. 
From the doc cellDidMount - called right after the <td> was added to the DOM 
See fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/resourceAreaColumns I am just looking at cellContent which is a hook but cant work out how to do the above from this routine

Comment: Hm did you specify your resources as a static list, or as data which can be fetched from a URL? If you supplied a static list, then refetch will not do anything. As far as I can see there is no other way to force the resources to re-render. Perhaps you could raise a feature request about it, so you can re-render from a static list? Either that or you'll have to figure out a way to find the correct `<td>` manually in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that cellClassNames can return a class and change the color

```
cellClassNames: function (arg) {
    var args = arg.resource._resource.ui.classNames;
    var parentId = arg.resource._resource.parentId;
    var tasks = arg.resource._resource.extendedProps.tasks;
    if (parentId != "" && tasks == 0) 
        return ['cellcolorred']                               
    else
        return ['cellcolorgreen']                              
}
```